# Different markups (html files) for different iOS devices in a Phonegap app?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, mobile, ios-universal-app

I am building an **universal iOS app** with **JS/HTML5/CSS3** and **Phonegap**. I am targeting the iPad, iPhone (old) and iPhone5, both orientations (portrait/landscape each).

Since I can't accomplish just ONE markup for all versions, I am wondering how I deal with that. I want to have one markup for one device with both orientations, so I will have three markups.

**Is the app able to detect which markup it needs depending on the device it runs? And if so, how? :)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You just have to make a device.model. This return the also the version. For exemple you can have iPad1.1 (for the first one)

```
function onDeviceReady() {

if (device.model == "iPad1,1") {
    //DO SOMETHING
}
else if (device.model == "iPad2,3") {
    //DO SOMETHING ELSE
}


}
```

[Here is the phonegap page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_device_device.model.md.html#device.model)

For exemple, I use this to active or not the possibility to take picture from my device. if it's iPad1 I disable the functionnality.

Hope it helps ;)